# Is this parallel recursion in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, recursion, synchronization

What is happening in the function below?

interpreting the output it appears to me that multiple recursions are occurring in parallel. Is that even possible (I didn't write any code to be executed parallely )

How can I fix this?

The top level function call:

```
for i = 1:n
        chNo = cluster.no(i);
        %if nodeArch.node(chNo).type ~= 'J';         %if type = J ie its an CH with no path to sink           
            nodeArch.node(chNo).dest = chNo;        %default self loop
            packetLength = nodeArch.node(chNo).data;
            packetLength = packetLength * roundArch.aggrFactor;
            path = num2str(i);
            clusterModel= forwardPacket(clusterModel, packetLength, chNo, nodeArch.node(chNo).connections, path);

            if nodeArch.node(chNo).dest == chNo
                nodeArch.node(chNo).type = 'J';        %set node as isolated CH       
            end
        %end
        nodeArch.node(chNo).data = 0 ;             %clearing local data
    end
```

the recursive function :

```
function clusterModel = forwardPacket(clusterModel, packetLength, chNo, connections,path)
    nodeArch = clusterModel.nodeArch;
    netArch  = clusterModel.netArch;
    cluster  = clusterModel.clusterNode;



    zone = nodeArch.node(chNo).zone;
    if  zone == 1            
        distance = sqrt((nodeArch.node(chNo).x - netArch.Sink.x)^2 + (nodeArch.node(chNo).y - netArch.Sink.y)^2);
        nodeArch.node(chNo).energy = afterTransmissionLoss( packetLength, netArch, distance, nodeArch.node(chNo).energy); 
        nodeArch.node(chNo).dest = 0; % ie sink 


        for j = 1:nodeArch.numNode
            if connections(j) == 1;
                netArch.Sink.connected(j) = 1;
                %disp(num2str(j));
            end
        end

        %This is the output block 

        path = strcat( path , ' > sink');        
        disp(path); 
        disp(netArch.Sink.data);
        netArch.Sink.data = netArch.Sink.data + 1;
        disp(netArch.Sink.data);

        %end of output block


        nodeArch.node(chNo).dest = 0;
    else
        n = length(cluster.no); % Number of CHs
        for i = 1:n
            destChNo = cluster.no(i);
            if nodeArch.node(destChNo).zone == zone-1
                distance = sqrt((nodeArch.node(chNo).x - nodeArch.node(destChNo).x)^2 + (nodeArch.node(chNo).y - nodeArch.node(destChNo).y)^2);
                if distance <= netArch.Yard.nodeRange    %check if CH is too far to send data
                    nodeArch.node(chNo).energy = afterTransmissionLoss( packetLength, netArch, distance, nodeArch.node(chNo).energy);
                    nodeArch.node(destChNo).energy = afterReceptionLoss( packetLength, netArch, nodeArch.node(destChNo).energy);
                    nodeArch.node(chNo).dest = destChNo;


                    %disp(strcat(num2str(destChNo),'>>' , num2str(destChNo)  ));
                    path = strcat( path , ' > ' ,num2str(chNo));
                    clusterModel = forwardPacket(clusterModel, packetLength, destChNo, connections, path);
                    nodeArch.node(chNo).dest = destChNo;                      
                    break;
                end
            end
        end
        nodeArch.node(chNo).type = 'J';        %set node as isolated CH
    end
    clusterModel.netArch = netArch;
    clusterModel.nodeArch = nodeArch;
end
```

the output:

```
2 >55 > sink
     0

     1

6 >72 > sink
     0

     1

7 >83 > sink
     0

     1

8 > sink
     0

     1

10 >106 >55 > sink
     1

     2

15 >186 > sink
     1

     2

16 >188 >55 > sink
     1

     2

17 >192 >330 > sink
     1

     2

21 > sink
     1

     2

22 > sink
     2

     3

26 >268 > sink
     3

     4

27 >271 > sink
     3

     4.....and so on
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what's wrong

in Java or C
when we write

```
a=b;  //where b is a structure/class
```

a is a reference of b.

in Matlab

a is another structure initialized with the values of b.

that was the issue.